# .htaccess tweak to get access to /sites/default/files

Tags: files, media, .htaccess

I would like to upload some files onto my drupal website like audio/video for promotion.

However, the .htaccess file in sites/default/files will not allow me. If I remove this file, it works but whenever a file is uploaded, the .htaccess is recreated again.

This is the .htaccess file. I already tried to comment line 2 and 3.

```
# Turn off all options we don't need.
Options None
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Set the catch-all handler to prevent scripts from being executed.
SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006
<Files *>
    # Override the handler again if we're run later in the evaluation list.
    SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2013_003
</Files>

# If we know how to do it safely, disable the PHP engine entirely.
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_flag engine off
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "will not allow me"? What are you actually trying, and what is the result?

Comment: I mean that I get an access denied error every time I try to download or play an mp3 file.

Comment: The permissions on the directory are allright (tried 777)

Comment: it's not the htaccess issue, its the directory permission, I assume you are not using linux, so go ahead right click on the folder, and change the permission to 750 recursively

Comment: Did you actually read the above comment?